# Getting hand-baggage only ticket

Tags: air-travel, etihad

I recently saw a sale on Etihad airways showing "Sale" under "Economy". It's website also says that you can have a [hand baggage only ticket](https://www.etihad.com/en/fly-etihad/baggage/hand-baggage-only), but I am unable to find it under Economy for any of the flights I am searching (Destination and from both are the countries covered by the destinations mentioned there). Can anyone please guide me how can I book one? Thanks!

Comment: It could be that you during your booking with Etihad you check a box that says something like "hand baggage only", and that there is no separate "hand baggage only" ticket classification per se.

Comment: There isn't any such a box/option there. It just says, "Value", "Choice" or "Choice Plus". ("Sale" too when there's a sale as I saw during Eid holidays).

Comment: Have you progressed all the way to paying for a ticket?  Because add ons for luggage could come after the route/ticket selection.

Comment: I have bought an economy ticket from Etihad's website on 2-3 occasions in the last month and there wasn't any such an option. Once you choose "Value", "Choice" etc, the fare applies accordingly (and can only increase once you choose seats or some extra services, etc.)

Comment: I checked Athens-Abu Dhabi. Some dates have it available, some do not.

Comment: Thanks @Anders I found the same for some routes/dates to AUH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fare class "Hand Baggage Only" isn't available on all Ethihad flights, and appears on the booking page only when the particular flight allows booking that fare class.

Here in the US, Ethihad has [a specific booking portal](https://www.etihad.com/en/fly-etihad/baggage/hand-baggage-only) for hand bagge only fares.